# Get selected option value angular js model

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to get selected value back to model but able to bind model value as selected item in select control.

View:

```
    <div  data-ng-repeat="BI in BulkInvoice">
     <select class="input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline" ng-disabled="!edit" data-ng-model="BI.DefaultCostType">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-selected="BI.DefaultCostType == item.ID"
            ng-repeat="item in costTypes"
            ng-value="item.ID">
       {{item.Name}}
   </option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.BulkInvoice = [{
DefaultCostType : 4
}];
```

Using above code, select control is able to set selected item based on id in BulkInvoice. But when user changes option on save click changed option is not sent back to model. Please assist.

Output html:

```
<select class="input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline" ng-disabled="!edit">
                                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                                    <!-- ngRepeat: item in costTypes --><option ng-selected="BI.DefaultCostType == item.ID" ng-repeat="item in costTypes" ng-value="item.ID" ng-model="BI.DefaultCostType" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="1">
                                                        Claim Cost
                                                    </option><!-- end ngRepeat: item in costTypes --><option ng-selected="BI.DefaultCostType == item.ID" ng-repeat="item in costTypes" ng-value="item.ID" ng-model="BI.DefaultCostType" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="3">
                                                        Expense - A&amp;O
                                                    </option><!-- end ngRepeat: item in costTypes --><option ng-selected="BI.DefaultCostType == item.ID" ng-repeat="item in costTypes" ng-value="item.ID" ng-model="BI.DefaultCostType" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="4">
                                                        Expense - D&amp;CC
                                                    </option><!-- end ngRepeat: item in costTypes --><option ng-selected="BI.DefaultCostType == item.ID" ng-repeat="item in costTypes" ng-value="item.ID" ng-model="BI.DefaultCostType" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="2" selected="selected">
                                                        Unspecified Cost Type
                                                    </option><!-- end ngRepeat: item in costTypes -->
                                                </select>
```

Comment: Can you show the generated html?

Comment: added output html

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- As your select element is not a multi select then you can use direct object instead of array of objects as you have to select only single value at a time.

**Solution :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.BulkInvoice = {
    DefaultCostType : 2
  };
    
    $scope.costTypes = [{
    "ID" : 1,
        "Name": "name1"
  },
    {
    "ID" : 2,
        "Name": "name2"
  },
    {
    "ID" : 3,
        "Name": "name3"
  },
    {
    "ID" : 4,
        "Name": "name4"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <select data-ng-model="CostType">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in costTypes" ng-selected="BulkInvoice.DefaultCostType == item.ID" ng-value="item.ID">
       {{item.Name}}
   </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what is CostType model here?

Comment: It is just `model` name. you can change it as per your suitable model name.